# Segmentation fault opening files

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

Im just trying to get started with learning C http://fromlearncodethehardway.com. However I'm stuck with a segmentation fault while trying to code up one of the examples from there. [Here's](http://pastebin.com/PH6bsawP) the link to my source code.
I tried using valgrind to further help with the debugging but I cant seem to figure out the issue. Here's the stack trace from valgrind.

```
   ~/Chardway$ valgrind ./ex17 db.dat g
   ==4423== Memcheck, a memory error detector                                                                                 == 4423== Copyright (C) 2002-2010, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
 ==4423== Using Valgrind-3.6.1-Debian and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
 ==4423== Command: ./ex17 db.dat g
 ==4423== 
 ==4423== Invalid read of size 1
 ==4423==    at 0x4EA4F1D: _IO_file_fopen@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (fileops.c:271)
 ==4423==    by 0x4E99DB5: __fopen_internal (iofopen.c:93)
 ==4423==    by 0x400A76: Database_open (ex17.c:65)
 ==4423==    by 0x400F7C: main (ex17.c:151)
 ==4423==  Address 0x722b is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
 ==4423== 
 ==4423== 
 ==4423== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
 ==4423==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x722B
 ==4423==    at 0x4EA4F1D: _IO_file_fopen@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (fileops.c:271)
 ==4423==    by 0x4E99DB5: __fopen_internal (iofopen.c:93)
 ==4423==    by 0x400A76: Database_open (ex17.c:65)
  ==4423==    by 0x400F7C: main (ex17.c:151)
.....

  ==4423== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
  ==4423== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 4 from 4)
 Segmentation fault
```

Any help on debugging would be great. Thanks!

Comment: Please show your code here.  Don't link to a different site.

Comment: Try to reduce your problem to a smaller testcase, and include your code here.

Comment: Using Pastebin on Stack Overflow is definitely a newbie error.

Comment: Have you detected which line in your code generates the segfault? This should be the start of your investigation.

Comment: @CarlNorum, I thought it'd be awkward to post a big chunk of irrelevant code and  linked it to pastebin.Since I wasnt sure of where the problem was!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your code you have `fopen` calls as `fopen(filename,'w');` & `fopen(filename,'r+');`. Those should be `fopen(filename,"w");` & `fopen(filename,"r+");`. The second parameter to [`fopen`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/functions/fopen.html) should be `const char *`
Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Incidentally, I think you mean http://c.learncodethehardway.org/
The address you gave doesn't resolve.